# JSP ajax json post return null as data

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

When I call method request.getParameter("username") I get null, why I do not get correct json string format? I also try to use JSON.stringify() but the result is same. I hope somebody will know what is wrong.

LoginServlet.java

```
 package org.SalonNamestaja.Controller.Ajax;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.SalonNamestaja.Services.LoginService;
import org.apache.catalina.User;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class LoginServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/login")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    List<User> users = new LinkedList<User>();

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public LoginServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        String jsonUsername = request.getParameter("username");
        String jsonPassword = request.getParameter("pass");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print("Hello " + jsonUsername + " " + jsonPassword );
    }

}
```

login_user.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Prijava korisnika</title>
<script src="javascript/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script >
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $name = $('#userName');
    var $pass = $('#password');

    $('#form').submit(function() {

    $.post("/SalonNamestaja/login", {username:$('#userName').val(), pass:$('#password').val()},function(data){
        alert(data);
    });

    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="form" action="/SalonNamestaja/login" method="post">
    Korisnicko ime:<input id="userName" type="text" name="userName"><br>
    Sifra:<input id="password" type="password" name="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Prijavi se">
</form>

<div id="welcometext">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do u get required value here : `$('#userName').val()`?

Comment: you are not returning an json response. Try Text type response.`text/text`.

Comment: When I put for type response `text/text` I get in alert box value of username, but when it load login servlet it again write `Hello null`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are thinking that javascript is working as php. 
You are getting your variables and sending $.post when document is ready - when you open your browser. I assume that you want to do it on form submit. Modify your script to something like:

```
<script>
function sendForm() {
// PUT YOUR CODE HERE
}
</script>
```

and modify your form, your submit button markup should look like:

```
<input type="submit" value="Prijavi se" onclick="sendForm()">
```

I'm not sure if this will solve your issue, you can check if any parameters are sent by iterating `request.getParameterNames`

Answer (score -1):

Probably, this is `multipart/form-data`

Try annotation `@MultipartConfig` and methods `request.getPart()`